# "Ich habe von Lisa ___, dass du krank bist.": erfahren/herausgefunden/gelernt/festgestellt

Tags: word-choice

> Ich habe von Lisa ___, dass du krank bist.
>
> (a) erfahren
>
> (b) herausgefunden
>
> (c) gelernt
>
> (d) festgestellt

Meiner Meinung nach gehen (a) und (c). (b) klingt ein bisschen, als ob ich mich sehr bemüht hätte, um die Information von Lisa zu bekommen, und passt hier deshalb nicht gut. (d) wäre zu formal für so eine kleine Information. Ist das richtig?

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach funktioniert nur "erfahren" - "gelernt" funktioniert nur im Englischen aber nicht im Deutschen...

Comment: I second Gerhard. _Gelernt_ = learned would be a false friend.

Comment: oder: (e) gehört

Comment: @Stephie: Vielleicht hat Lisa aber geschrieben.

Comment: Die Frage ist ganz schlecht, denn die Wortbedeutungen müssen nur übersetzt werden um zu sehen, welche falsch sind. Du bennenst nur wieso b nicht passt. A), C) und D) sollen wir erklären? Unklar was gefragt ist. Eigeninitiative? "Geht einfach nicht" ist ja wohl keine Erklärung.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich kann man schon etwas von jemanden "gehört" haben, auch wenn das Medium ein ganz anderes war.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um mal alles zusammenzuschreiben:

(a) -> ok.

> (a) Ich habe von Lisa erfahren, dass du krank bist.

(b) -> geht nur "ohne Lisa", also:

> (b) Ich habe herausgefunden, dass du krank bist.

Wenn Lisa *unbedingt* rein muss:

> (b) Ich habe dank Lisa herausgefunden, dass du krank bist.

(c) -> false friend:

> (c) Ich habe von Lisa gelernt, meine Schuhe zu binden.

(d) -> wie (b)

> (b) Ich habe festgestellt, dass du krank bist.

(e) -> umgangssprachliche Variante von (a), evtl. ungenau auch für schriftliche Kommunikation benutzt (wenn das Medium egal ist)

> (e) Ich habe von Lisa gehört, dass du krank bist.

Comment: Und noch eine Variante (wenn auch etwas rarer): Ich habe über Lisa mitgekriegt, dass du krank bist.

Comment: "von Lisa herausgefunden" ist richtig wenn sie zum Beispiel nur unter Druck mit der Information herausgerückt ist.